# In what cases is not recommended to use Laravel applications like Jetstream, Breeze, Laravel UI that provide Login and Registration?

Tags: laravel, scaffolding, laravel-jetstream

I would like to know in what cases is not recommended to use Laravel applications like Jetstream, Breeze, Laravel UI that provide Login and Registration services or what would be their limitations in front of a traditional login and registration system

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is a Backend Framework and so, it is totally agnostic about frontend, in fact you can only use fortify which give you the backend support for auth and implement any frontend you want.

Jetstream, Breeze, Laravel UI and other implementations that exist, are made to make a fast scafolding of a typical app with users etc...

But in fact, you can use Laravel as an api backend and use Sanctum for SPA.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#how-it-works